# How to realize MacOS-like (EN Intl) german umlauts behavior?

Tags: autohotkey, keymapping

I get a new Windows 10 Notebook, while I ran a MBP for long time. On MacOs I use an US Intl kezmap and I really like the shortcuts to write the german umlauts.

On MacOS I use {RAlt} + {u} followed by {a},{o},{u} or {s} to write the corresponding german Umlaut. To write a upper case umlaut I have to press {Shift} + {a},{o} or {u}.

I try to write an AHK script to reproduce this behavior, but unfortunately I have no success.

What I currently have created is this.

```
;Umlaut
#Persistent

    RAlt & a::
        GetKeyState, state, Shift
        if state = U
        SendInput {ASC 0228}            ;RAlt+a = lower case a-umlaut
        else Send, {ASC 0196}           ;RAlt+Shift+a = UPPER CASE A-umlaut
    return

    RAlt & o:: 
        GetKeyState, state, Shift
        if state = U
        SendInput {ASC 0246}            ;RAlt+o = lower case o-umlaut
        else Send, {ASC 0214}           ;RAlt+Shift+o = UPPER CASE O-umlaut
    return

    RAlt & u:: 
        GetKeyState, state, Shift
        if state = U
        SendInput {ASC 0252}            ;RAlt+u = lower case u-umlaut
        else Send, {ASC 0220}           ;RAlt+Shift+u = UPPER CASE U-umlaut
    return

    RAlt & s:: Send, {ASC 0223}     ;RAlt+s = RAlt+s, Eszett
    return
```

It works, but I really want the key combos described above. How can I reach this goal?

Comment: The code there is quite legacy, and it takes a really weird approach as well. Could be improved in quite a few ways. But, you said it works. So what's the actual question you have? You said you had no success, but then said you have a working script? What are you having trouble with.

Comment: The script does not the job I described. With this script I can write german umlauts with RAlt + consonant but this is not what I want to achieve. I want use RAlt + u followed by consonant or "s".

Comment: Ah, so pressing `RAlt + u` enters like umlaut typing mode, I see. Well what have you tried so far? I can take a look where it went wrong. I can see that the code in the post is just straight from Google.

Comment: Yes, it's an example from google which ich just modified to use RAlt insteat of capslock. 
I try to in put a sleep after ```LAlt & u``` and the just ```u::``` but this won't work as wanted.

Comment: ```LAlt & u::
    u::
        Send, {ASC 0252}```
This sends "ú" and then "ü". If I add {Backspace}, then the first character is deleted and only "ü" left over. But i also send {Backspace} ever if I hit "u".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to fix the code seen in the original post, it's quite legacy and uses a lot of weird approaches. To list and fix all of them:

[`#Persistent`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Persistent.htm) is doing nothing for us. It's useless here.

The `RAlt & key::` type hotkeys labels should use modifiers, and look like this `>!key::`.
The [`>!`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) modifier means right alt.

Usage of the legacy `GetKeyState` [command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm#command) should be replaced by the [`GetKeyState()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm#function) function.
Though, this isn't actually needed at all. The shift hotkey modifier `+` should just be used like so:

```
>!a::SendInput, ä
>!+a::SendInput, Ä
>!o::SendInput, ö
>!+o::SendInput, Ö
>!u::SendInput, ü
>!+u::SendInput, Ü
>!s::SendInput, ß
```

I also ditched the using the [ASC codes](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#asc), since I see no reason to use them.
I guess it would make the script file more flexible to be saved under a more primitive encoding, but eh.

So this was the code in your post done right.

---

And now to implement what you were actually looking to do:
Pressing `RAlt + u` enters a *umlaut typing mode*.

Easiest way of doing this, that I can think of, is just using creating context sensitive hotkeys with [`#If`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm).
Normally I wouldn't recommend the usage of `#If` in AHK v1, due to its downsides (as documented in the documentation), but it'll be more than fine for a little script like this. And it makes this a lot easier and neater.

So first lets create a `RAlt + u` hotkey, that sets the state of some variable to `true`:

```
>!u::UmlautTypingMode := true

Then we can create context sensitive hotkeys by always first checking the value of that variable:
>!u::UmlautTypingMode := true

#If, UmlautTypingMode ;start context sensitive hotkeys (if the variable value evaluates to true)
a::
    SendInput, ä
    UmlautTypingMode := false
return
+a::
    SendInput, Ä
    UmlautTypingMode := false
return
o::
    SendInput, ö
    UmlautTypingMode := false
return
+o::
    SendInput, Ö
    UmlautTypingMode := false
return
<!u::return
u::
    SendInput, ü
    UmlautTypingMode := false
return
+u::
    SendInput, Ü
    UmlautTypingMode := false
return
s::
    SendInput, ß
    UmlautTypingMode := false
return
#If ;end context sensitive hotkeys
```

As you can see, we unfortunately had to get rid of those sweet clean one-liner hotkeys, since `false` every time, and end code execution with a `return`.
Of course this could be compacted with some more advanced AHK, but I'll keep it simple.
And the small little `<!u::return` line inside the there is to make the initial `RAlt + u` press not produce a `ü`.

---

So that should be it. Works fine on my end at least.
Though, I've just now realized that with *"{RAlt} + {u} followed by {a},{o},{u} or {s}"* you may have meant that you'd keep typing umlauts for as long as RAlt is held down. If this was the case, the code needs some adjusting.
Right now you press **and release** `RAlt + u` to enter the *umlaut typing mode*.

---

Finally, as **a bonus**, here's the the code compacted down to a one-liner.
I know, it's stupid, I just couldn't resist, I love making these haha.

```
>!u::UmlautTypingMode := true
#If, UmlautTypingMode
a::
+a::
o::
+o::
u::
+u::
s::SendInput, % ((A_ThisHotkey = "s"), UmlautTypingMode := false) ? "ß" : ("¨" ((A_ThisHotkey ~= "\+") ? Format("{:U}", SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 0)) : SubStr(A_ThisHotkey, 0)))
>!u::return
#If
```

Also, no idea if this will work on different keyboard layouts.
Works for me at least.

---

**EDIT:**
A timeout requested was the comments. They're very easy and convenient to do with a [timer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm).
So, we change our `>!u::UmlautTypingMode := true` hotkey to this:

```
>!u::
    UmlautTypingMode := true
    SetTimer, Timeout, -2000
return
```

Negative number in the timer's period means it runs just **once** after 2000ms.

And now we of course have to also create the label (or function, I'll use a label here to keep it more simple) called `Timeout` (it's not a built in thing, we could've used any name here).

```
Timeout:
    UmlautTypingMode := false
return
```

This label can be placed for example at the bottom of the script.

Comment: Works for me too, with an exception of `<!u::UmlautTypingMode := true`. This doesn't work for me, I replace it by `<^>!u::UmlautTypingMode := true`.
One shortcoming I see. If i enter umlaut typing mode I have to finish it. Where should i place a timeout to leave the umlaut typing mode if I hit the combo exedentially?

Comment: Oops, I typo'd it to be a Left Alt instead of a Right Alt, that's why it doesn't work. And `<^>!` is used for `AltGr`, if you have an `AltGr` instead of a Right Alt, then use that. (Also fix `>!u::return` to use `AltGr`) And a [timer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) works great for timeouts. I'll edit that into the answer in a second.

Comment: Great work. I also make it round with a small addition:
```Send, ¨ ; print upper points to show you are in umlaut typing mode```
And ```SendInput, {Backspace}``` before each umlaut and also in Timeout label.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather suggest slightly different input approach: type in the letter and then use a script that substitutes the last character to the left of cursor.
I have done so when I worked a lot with german texts and turned out to be more effective compared to the method you describe. Also can replace the characters that are already in the text just by placing cursor by them and pressing same hotkey.

Here it is

```
dict := ComObjCreate("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.Add("a", "ä")
dict.Add("A", "Ä")
dict.Add("o", "ö")
dict.Add("O", "Ö")
dict.Add("u", "ü")
dict.Add("U", "Ü")

>!u::
    temp :=  clipboard  ; backup clipboard
    send +{left}
    send ^{insert}
    sleep 100
    c :=  clipboard
    found := false
    for key in dict {
        if (key==c) {
            v := dict.item[key]
            found := true
            send %v%
        }
    }
    if (found=false) {
        send {right}
        ; tooltip key not found
    }
    clipboard = %temp%
return
```